# Grails / Groovy Transform Exception

Tags: grails, groovy

I am getting the following exception when I try to compile the attached groovy class with the latest snapshoot of grails.  I d/l off of the build server today.  The key comment in the exception is: If this is not your own doing, please report this bug to the writer of the transform.

Exception:

> /u01/workspace/grails/grails-spring-social-core/grails-app/domain/grails/plugins/springsocial/UserConnection.groovy: -1: 
>       A transform used a generics containing ClassNode grails.plugins.springsocial.UserConnection for the 
>       method public static grails.plugins.springsocial.UserConnection create()  { ... }
>       directly. You are not suppposed to do this. Please create a new 
>       ClassNode refering to the old ClassNode and use the new ClassNode instead 
>       of the old one. Otherwise the compiler will create wrong descriptors and a 
>       potential NullPointerException in TypeResolver in the OpenJDK. If this is 
>       not your own doing, please report this bug to the writer of the transform.

So this looks like a couple of reported grails bugs, but they where dismissed as a bug in a plugin. Is this a grails problem or a groovy problem??

This talks about that is may be a groovy bug ... but this is way over my head.

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.groovy.devel/26130

What is the root cause of this?  Again is this a problem with the grails transform or is this a groovy compiler exception?  The following class is what I am trying to compile:

```
package grails.plugins.springsocial

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields=true)
class UserConnection implements Serializable {

    String userId
    String providerId
    String providerUserId
    String displayName
    String profileUrl
    String imageUrl
    String accessToken
    String secret
    String refreshToken
    Long rank
    Long expireTime

    static constraints = {
        userId nullable: false
        providerId nullable: false
        providerUserId nullable: false
        displayName nullable: true
        profileUrl nullable: true
        imageUrl nullable: true
        accessToken nullable: false
        secret nullable: true
        refreshToken nullable: true
        rank nullable: false
        expireTime nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "UserConnection"
        version false

        id composite:['userId', 'providerId', 'providerUserId']

        userId column:'userId',length:64
        providerId column:'providerId',length:128
        providerUserId column:'providerUserId',length:128
        displayName column:'displayName'
        profileUrl column:'profileUrl'
        imageUrl column:'imageUrl'
        accessToken column:'accessToken'
        secret column:'secret'
        refreshToken column:'refreshToken'
        rank column:'rank'
        expireTime column:'expireTime'
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of Grails?  `EqualsAndHashCode` has only been in since Groovy 1.8.0, and Grails 1.3.7 is on Groovy 1.7 isn't it?

Comment: The latest 2.0 snap off of the build server. This is a 1.8.3 groovy issue. I downgrade to 1.8.2 to get arround this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a Groovy 1.8.3 issue.  I downgraded to 1.8.2 and no longer had the issue.